# Compute the resistivity with an integral

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, integration

The professor gave us two formula in order to compute the resistivity of an object depending on the direction of the current. The first one corresponds to resistor equivalent to a series circuit (R is the total resistivity, $\rho$ is the resistance density, S the surface the current goes through and x the length of the object, in the direction of the current):

$dR={\rho(x)dx\over S(x)}$

The second one is for resistors equivalent to parallel circuits:

$d[{1\over R}]={dS\over \rho(x)dx}$

I have to say the one I struggle with is the second one. Indeed there are two infinitesimal elements of integration. I guess a solution could be rewriting $dS$ in terms of $dx$ in order to make it disappear below the fraction bar, but what if we cannot? And then what will be the borns of the integral: will there be two for the surface, or only one because we simplified the element $dx$?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have mixed up some terms in that $R$ is the resistance and $\rho$ is the resistivity?

[image]

In the second case you are adding the resistance of elements which are in parallel whose length is $dx$ and which have an area $dS$.

The resistivity $\rho(x)$ is the same throughout and so the integration gives the reciprocal of the resistance of the element of thickness $dx$

$\dfrac {1}{dR} = \dfrac {S}{\rho(x) \,dx} \Rightarrow dR=\dfrac {\rho(x)\,dx}{S }$

which is your first expression.

Comment: Ok thanks for the sketch! So basically both formula are the same?